# Does Sphinx index capital letters as the beginning of a word? If so what setting can over-ride this?

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

I just discovered an issue when searching for `iOS` as `IOS` and it wasn't found. So I tested on other words e.g `Market`. It is found by `Market` and `MARKET` and even `MARKEt`. Where it breaks is if I make any other letter caps, i..e `Camel Case`: `mArket`, 'MarKet', etc.

The only reason `iOS` works is it is in my `config file`.  Is there a setting that can tell me to ignore this, I rarely care about intialization.

Answer (score 0):

The 'default' `charset_table` is entirely case-insensitive (at least for English/ASCII!)
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-charset-table.html

Suggests you've configured your `charset_table` such that it no longer making searches case insensitive. And/or not ascii characters (the case folding wont deal with extended chars)

And/or wonder if you have configured `min_word_len`, such not indexing 3 letter words?
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-min-word-len.html